# Switching an image on hover over text / Without the use of jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, image, switch-statement

I am making a portfolio page as a school project. My idea is to have an image with titles underneath and whenever I hover over a headline (let's say there will be a headline for Design Manual, Animation, Storyboard etc.) the image will change to a one corresponding to the headline that can be clicked and will lead to a subpage with more information about the chosen theme. I can't use any jQuery yet only javascript. 
I wrote this piece of code that is working however it is too long and I would like to know if there is a shorter possibility. I was thinking an array with switch function? However I am very new to javascript so I could not put it together myself when I tried. Any help is appreciated.

```
let thumbnail = document.querySelector("#thumbN");

let buttonOne = document.querySelector("#ButtonOne");
let buttonTwo = document.querySelector("#ButtonTwo");
let buttonThree = document.querySelector("#ButtonThree");
let buttonFour = document.querySelector("#ButtonFour");
let buttonFive = document.querySelector("#ButtonFive");
let buttonSix = document.querySelector("#ButtonSix");
let buttonSeven = document.querySelector("#ButtonSeven");
let buttonEight = document.querySelector("#ButtonEight");
let buttonNine = document.querySelector("#ButtonNine");
let buttonTen = document.querySelector("#ButtonTen");

buttonOne.addEventListener("mouseover", doBackgroundOne);
buttonOne.addEventListener("mouseout", removeBackOne);

buttonTwo.addEventListener("mouseover", doBackgroundTwo);
buttonTwo.addEventListener("mouseout", removeBackTwo);

buttonThree.addEventListener("mouseover", doBackgroundThree);
buttonThree.addEventListener("mouseout", removeBackThree);

buttonFour.addEventListener("mouseover", doBackgroundFour);
buttonFour.addEventListener("mouseout", removeBackFour);

buttonFive.addEventListener("mouseover", doBackgroundFive);
buttonFive.addEventListener("mouseout", removeBackFive);

buttonSix.addEventListener("mouseover", doBackgroundSix);
buttonSix.addEventListener("mouseout", removeBackSix);

buttonSeven.addEventListener("mouseover", doBackgroundSeven);
buttonSeven.addEventListener("mouseout", removeBackSeven);

buttonEight.addEventListener("mouseover", doBackgroundEight);
buttonEight.addEventListener("mouseout", removeBackEight);

buttonNine.addEventListener("mouseover", doBackgroundNine);
buttonNine.addEventListener("mouseout", removeBackNine);

buttonTen.addEventListener("mouseover", doBackgroundTen);
buttonTen.addEventListener("mouseout", removeBackTen);

function doBackgroundOne() {
    thumbnail.classList.add('BackOne');
    console.log("fatality");    
}

function removeBackOne() {
    thumbnail.classList.remove('BackOne');
}


function doBackgroundTwo() {
    thumbnail.classList.add('BackTwo');
    console.log("fatality");    
}

function removeBackTwo() {
    thumbnail.classList.remove('BackTwo');
}


function doBackgroundThree() {
    thumbnail.classList.add('BackThree');
    console.log("fatality");    
}

function removeBackThree() {
    thumbnail.classList.remove('BackThree');
}


function doBackgroundFour() {
    thumbnail.classList.add('BackFour');
    console.log("fatality");    
}

function removeBackFour() {
    thumbnail.classList.remove('BackFour');
}


function doBackgroundFive() {
    thumbnail.classList.add('BackFive');
    console.log("fatality");    
}

function removeBackFive() {
    thumbnail.classList.remove('BackFive');
}


function doBackgroundSix() {
    thumbnail.classList.add('BackSix');
    console.log("fatality");    
}

function removeBackSix() {
    thumbnail.classList.remove('BackSix');
}


function doBackgroundSeven() {
    thumbnail.classList.add('BackSeven');
    console.log("fatality");    
}

function removeBackSeven() {
    thumbnail.classList.remove('BackSeven');
}


function doBackgroundEight() {
    thumbnail.classList.add('BackEight');
    console.log("fatality");    
}

function removeBackEight() {
    thumbnail.classList.remove('BackEight');
}


function doBackgroundNine() {
    thumbnail.classList.add('BackNine');
    console.log("fatality");    
}

function removeBackNine() {
    thumbnail.classList.remove('BackNine');
}

function doBackgroundTen() {
    thumbnail.classList.add('BackTen');
    console.log("fatality");    
}

    function removeBackTen() {
    thumbnail.classList.remove('BackTen');
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="thumbnail" id="thumbN"></div>

    <section class="palete">

        <a href="http://www.takodesign.one/mobile/index.html" id="ButtonOne" class="firewatch">First Site</a>


        <a href="http://takodesign.one/index2.html" id="ButtonTwo" class="mountains">Redesign</a>


        <a href="https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1nl9VJkUj7cN01YNmtsdDVVT2c" id="ButtonThree" class="storyboard">Storyboard</a>


        <a href="http://www.takodesign.one/animation/index.html" id="ButtonFour" class="animation">Animation</a>


        <a href="http://www.takodesign.one/animation_interactive/animation.html" id="ButtonFive" class="interactive">Interactive</a>


        <a href="http://www.takodesign.one/project/index.html" id="ButtonSix" class="redesign">Group project</a>


        <a href="documents/abeona_report.pdf" id="ButtonSeven" class="abeona">Abeona</a>


        <a href="documents/design_manual.pdf" id="ButtonEight" class="visual">Visual identity</a>


        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zy-ZeRD4Img" id="ButtonNine" class="reportage">Reportage</a>


        <a href="https://vimeo.com/219885010" id="ButtonTen" class="filming">Stronger together</a>

    </section>
```

Comment: Can you show us your html?

Comment: So, if you have 50 buttons, you will copy/paste and repeat the same code 50 times?

Comment: @JeremyThille `however it is too long and I would like to know if there is a shorter possibility` I assume that this is his question, how to do shorter and cleaner code without jQuery.

Comment: instead of id you can give a class to buttons.so you can add one event listner and get the clicked button index. and for the functions create something like `doBackground(){index}` then you can pass index to the function `doBackground(1);`.inside the function you can use a switch.also for classnames you can use `Back7` instead of `BackSeven` so you can add them dynamically or you can use inline css so you dont need to have lot of classes.also you can arrane image url fore dinamic way like `images/img1.jpg,images/img2.jpg...`

Comment: And why you need a different class? Can't you just toggle class and set the style in the css? What exactly the style you want to set? Maybe it will be better to add the css too..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*How about you loop through all the buttons on your page and add event listeners* :

**Steps**

- Get all buttons on your page
- Loop through buttons collection
- While designing your HTML you can apply specific `css` class as an identifier
  on buttons you would like to add event listen to, use this check
  within loop.
- Define just one `mouseover` and `mouseout` functions to add and remove classes, attach them as
  event listener and pass class name via parameter (you may define
  these classes in some pattern i.e. buttonid + class )

sample code below

```
var allButtonsOnYourPage = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
for (var i = 0; i < allButtonsOnYourPage.length; i++) {
    var button = allButtonsOnYourPage[i];
    //check button's class
var appliedCssClass = button .className
    if(appliedCssClass == 'yourCustomClass'){
    button.addEventListener("mouseover", applyBackground, false);
    addEventListener('mouseover', applyBackground.bind(null, event, 'pass class to be applied'));
   addEventListener('mouseout', applyBackground.bind(null, event, 'pass class to be removed'));

}

}

function applyBackground(applyThisclass) {
    document.querySelector("#thumbN").classList.add(applyThisclass);

}

function removeBackground(removeThisclass) {
    document.querySelector("#thumbN").classList.remove(removeThisclass);
}
```

Comment: Sorry I am really new to JS (+- 2 weeks of coding), do I have to specify "yourCustomClass" ? And I am not really sure what is the purpose 'pass class to be applied' in the code, could you explain please? And if I get it correctly then the functions will remove and apply classes according to the buttons it checked in the previous statement? Also the part with (applyThisClass and remove) is a bit unclear to me.

Comment: I know it's a lot to ask but could you maybe write a working sample in jfiddle so I could see it in work? I am really lost and have to hand-in the assingment by tomorrow :/

Comment: Vitek - it is an working example please try to integrate and come back if you have questions/errors ! best of luck :)